# How to find total time between time intervals defined by start and end columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I have a pandas DataFrame:

[image]

I want to calculate the diffrence between confirm and cancel in the following way:

For date 13.01.2020 and desk_id 1.0 : 10:35:00 – 8:00:00 + 12:36:00 – 11:36:00 + 20:00:00 - 13:36:00

I was able to perform these actions only for a desk with one hour of confirm and cancel. By one hour I mean that in date for desk_id I have only one row for confirm and cancel time. The interesting diff and I get when I subtract  from confirm 8:00:00 and from 20:00:00 the cancel time and add them together.

For many hours, I can't put it together. By mamy hour I mean that desk_id in one date have few rows with cancel and confirm time. I would like to choose the date, desk_id and calculate the desk occupancy time - the difference between confirm and cancel for each desk.

Output should looks like:
[image: 2]

I would like to find periods of time when a desk is free.
In my data can be many confirms and cancels for desk in one date.

I did it for one hour confirm and cancel:

```py
df_1['confirm'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_1['confirm'].astype(str))
df_1['diff_confirm'] = df_1['confirm'].apply(lambda x: x - datetime.timedelta(days=0, hours=8, minutes=0))
df_1['cancel'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_1['cancel'].astype(str))
df_1['diff_cancel'] = df_1['cancel'].apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(days=0, hours=20, minutes=0)-x)
```

and this works.

Any tips?

Comment: thank you for correcting the questions!

Comment: What do you mean by "one hour" or "many hours" of confirm and cancel?  Do you mean the difference between the values in `confirm` and `cancel` columns?  Please add expected output (what you hope to get for the input you provided) and also clarify the calculation logic that you hope to implement.  What is the calculation that needs to be performed for "many hours" and how does that differ from the calculation for "one hour"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I corrected, is the question understandable now?

Comment: The question is missing some data. But from what you have given I can undestand these. Please correct me if I did say anything wrong and please make sure to include these in the question as well.

1) The job starts at 08:00 and ends at 20:00 
2) You want to calculate it for each DAY and at each DESK ID
 
What I don't really get is you said your code works. I didn't quite catch what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not make it entirely clear what format you need your results in, but I assume it is okay to put them in a separate dataframe.  So this solution operates on each group of rows defined by values of `date` and `desk_id` and computes the total time for each group, with output placed in a new dataframe:

Code to create your input dataframe:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date': [pd.Timestamp('2020-1-13'), pd.Timestamp('2020-1-13'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2020-1-13'), pd.Timestamp('2020-1-14'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2020-1-14'), pd.Timestamp('2020-1-14')],
        'desk_id': [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0],
        'confirm': ['10:36:00', '12:36:00', '09:36:00', '10:36:00', '12:36:00',
                    '15:36:00'],
        'cancel': ['11:36:00', '13:36:00', '11:36:00', '11:36:00', '14:36:00',
                   '16:36:00']
    }
)
```

Solution:

```
df['confirm'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['confirm'])
df['cancel'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['cancel'])

# function to compute total time each desk is free
def total_time(df):
    return (
        (df.iloc[0]['confirm'] - timedelta(days=0, hours=8, minutes=0)) +
        (df['confirm'] - df['cancel'].shift()).sum() +
        (timedelta(days=0, hours=20, minutes=0) - df.iloc[-1]['cancel'])
    )

# apply function to each combination of 'desk_id' and 'date', producing
# a new dataframe
df.groupby(['desk_id', 'date']).apply(total_time).reset_index(name='total_time')


#    desk_id          date       total_time
# 0      1.0    2020-01-13  0 days 10:00:00
# 1      1.0    2020-01-14  0 days 11:00:00
# 2      2.0    2020-01-13  0 days 10:00:00
# 3      2.0    2020-01-14  0 days 09:00:00
```

The function takes the difference between the first value of `confirm` and 8:00:00, takes differences between each `confirm` and preceding `cancel` values, and then the difference between 20:00:00 and the last value of `cancel`.  Those differences added together to produce the final value.

Answer (score 0):

One guess at what you're trying to do (I still can't fully understand, but here's an attempt):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta as td
#create the dataframe
a = pd.DataFrame({'data':['2020-01-13','2020-01-13','2020-01-14'],'desk_id':[1.0,1.0,1.0],'confirm':['10:36:00','12:36:00','13:14:00'],'cancel':['11:36:00','13:36:00','13:44:00']})

def get_avail_times(df,start_end_delta=td(hours=12)):
    df['confirm'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['confirm'])
    df['cancel'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['cancel'])
    #group by the two keys so that we can perform calculations on the specific groups!!
    df_g = df.groupby(['data','desk_id'], as_index=False).sum()
    df_g['total_time'] = start_end_delta - df_g['cancel'] + df_g['confirm'] 
    return df_g.drop('confirm',1).drop('cancel',1)

output = get_avail_times(a)
```

Which gives the output:

```
         data  desk_id      total_time
0  2020-01-13      1.0 0 days 10:00:00
1  2020-01-14      1.0 0 days 11:30:00
```

The key here is to use the .groupby() function which we can then sum together to essentially perform the equation:

> total_time = 20:00 + sum_confirm_times - sum_cancel_times - 08:00

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please select or approve it, thanks :)